# Как сделать функцию , которая возвращает setTimout

Tags: javascript

Как сделать функцию , которая возвращает setTimout с переменной заданной как аргумент функции.
Есть функция -

```
function borderWarning(elem){
    let TIME = setTimeout(() => {
        elem = 'box-shadow: 0 0 6px #F32828';
    },50);
    setTimeout(() => {
        clearTimeout(TIME);
        elem = 'border-color: none';
    },500);
}
```

Нужно что бы elem (переданный как аргумент) находился в setTimeot , в стрелочной функции

Comment: "находился в setTimeot" - ??

Comment: @Igor да, elem не передается в стрелочную функцию , он его не видит . Как сделать что бы область видимости доходила до setTimeout

Comment: "elem не передается в стрелочную функцию , он его не видит" - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: @Igor очень просто , любой IDE подсвечивает аргумент функции , если он там как либо задействован

Comment: Я пишу код в Notepad-е. Повторяю свой вопрос.

Comment: Зачем вам это нужно? 5 лет программирую, ну здесь явный пример болезни "Новичок". Всё надо усложнить.

Comment: Отвечу сразу на два вопроса , "Я пишу код в Notepad-е. Повторяю свой вопрос" - стрелочная функция в данной ситуации , как я понимаю отдельная функция и она не видит аргументы другой функции , хоть в ней и находится . Так вот , я хочу расширить область видимости аргумента или стрелочной функции , чтобы они взаимодействовали . "Зачем вам это нужно? " - для проэкта

Comment: Она все прекрасно видит. См. ответ.

Comment: И вообще как вы аргументу функции присваиваете данные, если аргумент функции изменить, это изменение будет работать только внутри функции.

Comment: В качестве аргумента я передаю , например - elem.style , тут должно быть явное присваивание

Comment: Эти присваивания никак не повлияют на значение переменной, использованной как параметр вызова `borderWarning`.

Comment: Как тогда передать его , если не переменой ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код внутри функции `borderWarning` не использует переменную `elem`, а только присваивает ей значения. Эти присваивания никак не повлияют на значение переменной, использованной как параметр вызова `borderWarning`.

```
function borderWarning(obj) {
  ...
  obj.prop = "new value";
  ...
}

var o = { prop: "old value" };
borderWarning(o);
```

Comment: Я знаю что это прямое присваивание , у меня мягко говоря одинаковые куски кода , и я хочу использовать одну строку , тем самым сжать его .

Comment: @mbfilipp Я ничего не понял.

Comment: Этот код рабочий? Если да , то что я не так объяснял?

Comment: @mbfilipp Этот код рабочий.

Comment: Эх... Допустил одну ошибку в коде , спасибо за ответ)